# Extract value of `href` atributes using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When using Nokogiri to parse HTML and selecting `a` elements with `class="favorite"`:

```
galleries = doc.css(".favourite a")
#doc variable contains return of Nokogiri::HTML(source_page.body)
```

`puts galleries` returns:

```
<a href="/galleries/6730">...</a>
<a href="/favourites/40565414">...</a>
<a href="/galleries/10851">...</a>
<a href="/favourites/40850848">...</a>
```

How can I extract only `/galleries/[0-9]+` values of `href` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
galleries.xpath("@href[contains(., 'galleries')]").map(&:value)
# => ["/galleries/6730", "/galleries/10851"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using more Ruby and less XPath

```
doc.css('.favourite a').map{ |a| a['href'][%r{galleries/\d+}] }.compact
```